# What is meant by a certain Point of view

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Look at the following conversation:

> Luke: Ben! Why didn't you tell me? You told me that Darth Vader betrayed and murdered my father.
>
> Obi-Wan: Your father... was seduced by the Dark Side of the Force. He ceased to be the Jedi Anakin Skywalker and "became" Darth Vader. When that happened, the good man who was your father was destroyed. So, what I told you was true... ***from a certain point of view***.
>
> Luke: ***A certain point of view?*** **From another certain point of view**, it could be a blatant lie.

I am confused about how 'from a certain point of view' is being used above. How is it that one point of view makes one thing true and another makes it a lie? I understand point of view to mean as viewing something from a vantage point. But, I fail to understand what that vantage point is in the above context. Please shed some light on this usage.

Comment: Hi Shikha, welcome to ELL! This is an excellent question, your current understanding explained and given plenty of context. I appreciate you taking the time and effort to post a well-considered question, and hope to see many more from you in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> point of view

is being used to mean

> interpretation

As with many things in life, there usually is more than one way to interpret events, their meanings, and the motivations behind them.

A very famous film by Akira Kurosawa

> [Rashomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashomon)

explores this phenomenon, and from which

> the [Rashomon Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashomon_effect)

has been derived.

In your example, when Anakin Skywalker became Darth Vader, Obi-Wan is saying Anakin died *figuratively* since his entire being changed and would not be recognisable as Anakin Skywalker.

Luke, on the other hand, is saying that his Father never *literally* died.  So they are talking about the same event from two different perspectives or "points of view".

Comment: Peter what are those two different perspectives here? How does one decide what is that perspective? Is it that we randomly choose facts or have some notions and we form that the basis to move ahead and consider and issue?

Comment: The facts would not be randomly chosen but rather the facts *you* would need to make a decision. For example, Anakin Skywalker and Darth Vader have the same DNA, the same fingerprints, and the same memories, for Luke he is the same person though changed from Anakin Skywalker to Darth Vader.  To Obi-Wan, he is no longer the same since his motivations and attitudes have changed. Another example would be if you had a relative or friend that you knew and then you see them years later. They have changed (become older). Are they the same person? Some might say yes, and some might say no.

Comment: Can you joke with them in the same way as before? Do the two of you get on the same way as before? Has life changed either of you?

Comment: Peter I have not understood the point about the relatives here. Could you please explain again?

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon how you understand (or view) the identity of a person.

> Anakin Skywalker and Darth Vader are one person

or

> In becoming Darth Vader, Vader was a new person with new values, a new identity. More, he destroyed (murdered) the Anakin identity.

From a Jedi's perspective, way of looking at things, **view** the very soul of Anakin was destroyed in the creation of Vader.

Comment: djna can I say From a Jedi's perspective to mean according to Jedi or should I say according to Jedi's perspective? Which one is correct? and what is the difference between them?

Comment: The "from a/an xxxx perspective" is very common usage, perhaps think of it as standing in that person's shoes, with that person's framework of understanding. "according" feels more appropriate when referring to rules and structures. "according to the principles of the Catholic Church"